# How do I use hasNext() along with Scanner in a while loop in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have only a few weeks of experience in Java and I'm having trouble with an assignment I was given in my Intro to Java class. The assignment is write a program that allows the user to input a letter and determines whether the letter is a vowel or a consonant. The code I wrote for that works fine, but when I try to add in a while loop so the user can enter as many letters as they'd like, the program no longer works. My professor says the loop should continue until reaching EOF, and I followed the outline he gave but I'm still having trouble. This is the entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowel 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    

       String w;

       while(in.hasNext())
       {
            w = in.next();

            System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
            char letter = in.nextLine().charAt(0);

            int ascii;
            ascii =((int) letter);

            Boolean valid = true; 

            if (ascii < 65 || ((ascii > 90) && (ascii < 97)) || ascii > 122)
            {
                    System.out.println(letter + " is an invalid input");
                     valid = false;
            }
            else if(valid)
            {
                    System.out.print(letter + " is a ");

                    switch (ascii)
                    {
                            case 'a' : 
                            case 'A' : System.out.println("vowel");
                                       break;
                            case 'e' : 
                            case 'E' : System.out.println("vowel");
                                       break;
                            case 'i' : 
                            case 'I' : System.out.println("vowel");
                                       break;
                            case 'o' : 
                            case 'O' : System.out.println("vowel");
                                       break;
                            case 'u' : 
                            case 'U' : System.out.println("vowel");
                                       break;
                            default  : System.out.println("consonant");  
                    }
            }

       }
    }
}
```

When I run the code as is, the console just stays blank and if I type anything in (just trying to get it to do something), I get an error that says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0."
The code works without the while loop and it also works with a while loop using a counter, so I know my mistake has something to do with the hasNext(). If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Post the rest of your code.

Comment: Your mistake is most likely on the line where the exception was thrown.  I suggest you look at that line as `hasNext()` will not throw this exception.  i.e. the problem is most likely in code you haven't shown.  You can test this yourself by running the code in the question and you will see that there is no exception thrown.

Comment: Btw: you won't reach an `EOF` with `System.in` as the source. A `#nextxxx()` call will always request more input.

Comment: Entire code posted! @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Thank you! I just posted the entire code but unfortunately we have not covered exceptions in my class yet. I'm going to check my textbook and hopefully what you've said will make a little more sense, I appreciate your input :) @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring `w` and reading another line, **but** you haven't checked that there is a line to read or that the line you read isn't empty. You could do so with something like

```
if (in.hasNextLine()) { // <-- check if there is a line.
    String line = in.nextLine(); // <-- read the line.
    if (!line.isEmpty()) { // <-- make sure there is at least one character.
        char letter = line.charAt(0); // <-- get the first character.
```